# Report bug for any app on Google Play

Tags: bugs, crash-reports, feedback

Is there a bug report feature which can be used to report bugs with any app hosted on Google Play?

I'm thinking that most developers will welcome feedback on their apps, so would expect this mechanism to be built into the Play platform; or at least for a service to be available for this purpose.

I've found options to report issues with Google's own apps / the Play platform itself, and obviously some apps have built in a feedback feature, but for many I can't find any way to feed back to the developers.

Comment: I think the easiest way to give feedback to a developer is by using the Google Play Store comments; many developers read those comments in order to find out what users like/don't like to improve their applications.

Comment: I would wager many developers (particularly indie ones) would prefer an email to a review. They receive no notification for new reviews, so unless they dedicate time to checking them regularly they may not see them in a reasonable timeframe. Every app should have a "contact" link at the bottom of the Play Store listing.

Comment: @GiantTree took the words out my mouth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is no, the Google Play Store does not include a built in bug report feature.

In order to submit a bug report, you should first check the developer website to see if such a function is provided.  If not, your best option is to email the developer or, if the issue concerns other users, post a public comment.